# Array in PhP for Wordpress / foreach loop in an array

Tags: php, arrays, wordpress

I am building a theme in Wordpress where I need to register menus on the go.

The code below works just fine, but it's static (in functions.php)

```
function register_my_menus() {
register_nav_menus(

  array(
  'header-menu' => __( 'Header Menu' ),
  'footer-menu' => __( 'Footer Menu' ),
  'left-menu' => __( 'Left Menu' )
  )                 
)};
```

However, I have my menu list stored in the array below. How do I use this in register_nav_menus above? I tried to run a foreach, but it's not so easy to do that inside of an array, right?

```
$list_of_menus[];
```

The array above contains the following:

```
'fdsfds_fds' => __( 'fdsfds fds' ),
'Its_my_life' => __( 'Its my life' ),
'header-menu' => __( 'Header Menu' ),
'footer-menu' => __( 'Footer Menu' ),
'left-menu' => __( 'Left Menu' )
```

Thank you!

Comment: Belongs on wordpress.stackexchange.com


Comment: `register_nav_menus($list_of_menus);` - assuming your list is in the proper format, of course.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hardly seems worthy of a full answer, but here goes:

If your array is:

```
$list_of_menus = array(
    'fdsfds_fds' => __( 'fdsfds fds' ),
    'Its_my_life' => __( 'Its my life' ),
    'header-menu' => __( 'Header Menu' ),
    'footer-menu' => __( 'Footer Menu' ),
    'left-menu' => __( 'Left Menu' )
);
```

Then registering is a matter of:

```
register_nav_menus($list_of_menus);
```

Of course, this may depend on *how* you are loading `$list_of_menus` - can you load it in time / before the register_nav_menus call has to be made?

**Edit**
There's a few ways to build your array.  Above is the first.  Further, you can add elements to this array like so:

```
$slug = "my_menu_slug';
$name = __('My Menu Name');

$list_of_menus[$slug] = $name;
```

Comment: Thank you. I guess that solves half my problem. Now the real problem is that, as I'm new to arrays, is how to register them properly. I had each line as a string, but that's wrong! So I tried with $regarr[] = $slug => $rname;, but that's not allowed either. So, how do I write an array properly? Any help would be much appreciated!